# Linq Where clause with dynamic conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

For an API call I have a string being submitted to obtain matching inventory items. The following works as intended:

```
    public IEnumerable<Inventory> GetInventoryByItem(string item)
    {
        return _ctx.Pairs
            .Include(x => x.Attribute)
            .Where(x => (x.Attribute.Item == item));
    }
```

My issue is wanting to add multiple conditions to the function to obtain something to the effect of :

```
    public IEnumerable<Inventory> GetInventoryByItem(string[] items)
    {
        return _ctx.Pairs
            .Include(x => x.Attribute)
            .Where(x => foreach(string item in items){ return x.Attribute.Item == item });
    }
```

The above function obviously does not work. I know I can get the collection of items by calling the above function externally in a loop, but my concern is I'm hitting the database with multiple nearly identical statements when I could just consolidate it into one. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Use `items.Contains` **inside** the `Where` clause.

Comment: `.Where(x => items.Contains(x.Attribute.Item));`, or `.Where(x => items.Any(item => x.Attribute.Item == item));`

Comment: @NetMage oh, right! thanks, deleted

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `Any`

```
public IEnumerable<Inventory> GetInventoryByItem(string[] items)
{
        return _ctx.Pairs
            .Include(x => x.Attribute)
            .Where(x => items.Any(a=> a == x.Attribute.Item));
  // OR
     return _ctx.Pairs
            .Include(x => x.Attribute)
            .Where(x => items.Contains(x.Attribute.Item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want a generic function, that takes as input a sequence of objects of some class and a sequence of predicates on properties of this class, and you want as output a sequence containing those objects from the input sequence where all predicates would return true

As an example:

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = ...
var predicates = [0] person is born in 1961
                 [1] person is born in Honolulu
                 [2] person is a politician
```

As output you want the sequence with all Politicians that were born in Honolulu in 1961

Let's do this as an extension method, so you can use it as a LINQ statement. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

What you do is concatenate `Where` statements. Parameter `predicate` in where is a `Func<TSource, bool>`. So we need a sequence of `Func<TSource, bool>` as predicates.

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> Where( this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IEnumerable<Func<TSource, bool>> predicates)
{
    // TODO: handle null source and null predicates

    IEnumerable<TSource> result = source;
    foreach (Func<TSource, bool> predicate in predicates)
    {
        result = result.Where(predicate);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage example:

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = ...
var honoluluPresidents = persons.Where(new[]
{
     person => person.BirthPlace == "Honolulu",
     person => person.BirthDate.Year == 1961,
     person => person.Job == "politician",
});
```

Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: But how is that superior to combining predicates with and/or? I also think you're missing something (like a `[]`) in your usage example.

Comment: Well, it was your choice not to provide a use case where software would come up with an unknown sequence of predicates. Maybe the operator created a list of predicates by selecting predicates from a selection box. Your proposal to use a sequence of strings is even worse, because there is absolutely no check that the used strings represent proper predicates. You are right about the [] though. Feel free to improve the answer

Comment: I wasn’t talking about strings - I was talking about logical operators ‘&&’ and ‘||’.

Comment: Yet in your question you write `GetInventoryByItem(string[] items)`, I assumed you want to identify the predicates in your where using a sequence of strings. If that's not the case, then what did you mean?

Comment: But that's not my question :D , OP is @anesthetic.
I think what he wanted to do is filter a collection of someting x based on whether this x has all item attributes passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant `.All()` by your `foreach`?

```
public IEnumerable<Inventory> GetInventoryByItems(string[] items)
{
    return _ctx.Pairs
        .Include(x => x.Attribute)
        .Where(x => items.All(item => x.Attribute.Item == item));
}
```